# Exporting Collada from Blender distorts model and animation

Tags: animation, export, blend-files, collada, dae

I am making an iOS AR app using Xcode and Swift.

I am using a model (along with animations) created by someone else in Blender. They have given me the .blend file, but I need a .dae (collada) file to work with Xcode. When I attempt to export the model in collada, it gets distorted, even though it works fine originally in Blender.

In Blender (.blend) file:
[image]

In collada (.dae) file:
[image]

By the way I am exporting using Blender's default export settings. I have never used Blender before, so does anyone know what happened and how I can fix this (is this a settings issue)?

Thanks!

Comment: Try applying all transforms to the armature and mesh before you export (Object > Apply > All Transforms).

Comment: @scurest thanks for the reply! However, I tried it and it seemed that it still doesn't work